# How to install mdwtools package with MiKTeX?

Tags: packages, installing

I followed the instruction from CTAN: http://docs.miktex.org/faq/packages.html, then I ran the command:
`mpm --verbose --install mdwtools`.
The system said the package was installed successfully, but I couldn't find `mdwtools` folder under my `C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex` directory. Does this package require a special installation? I'm current using TexMaker on Windows 7. Most of the time, I just include the line: `\usepackage{X}`, and TexMaker will automatically install the package. However, with `mdwtools`, nothing happened! So what can I do in this case? Thank you.

Comment: I don't use MikTeX, but I suspect that the problem might be connected with the fact that you can install it as a user and as an admin; if you install a package then with wrong privileges, things might go wrong (I suppose).

Comment: @mbork: Thanks a lot for your quick reply. However, I ran it as administrator though, and TexMaker keeps telling me it couldn't find the .sty file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mdwtools is not a single sty but a bundle of packages. To trigger the automatic on-the-fly installation you would have to use one of this packages in your document e.g. `\usepackage{mdwtab}`.

You installed the package in user mode so it should now be in one of the miktex trees in your user profile. Probably in the one called UserConfig or UserInstall. Look up the path in miktex settings (user mode).

It could be that the `mpm` command didn't update the  FNDB so run either `initexmf -u` on the command line, or use miktex settings (user mode).